How do I iterate within columnDefs in DataTables
I'm building a DataTable with SearchPanes, trying to construct custom options, more or less following this documentation: https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/customFiltering/customOptionConditions.html
Now, the options are in fact within a separate array, like this e.g.:
cities = ['London','Edinburgh'];
So, instead of having fixed options like this:
options: [
    {
        label: 'London',
        value: function (rowData, rowIdx) {
            return rowData[3] == 'London';
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Edinburgh',
        value: function (rowData, rowIdx) {
            return rowData[3] == 'Edinburgh';
        }
    },
]

.. I want to construct them dynamically, iterating over the array, like this:
options: [
    cities.forEach((element) =>
    {
        label = element,
        value = function (rowData, rowIdx) {
            return rowData[3] == element;
        }
    },
]

But this doesn't really work, and I cannot figure out where I'm doing wrong, mainly due to my lack of javascript knowledge. I'm probably not constructing the object in the right way. I've tried various things, but to no avail, usually getting back an "Unexpected token" error.
So, please enlighten me =)

Finally, I found the answer here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/71938/loop-with-columns-searchpanes-options
